# How to handle form submissions?

Tags: form, post

So I am coming from WordPress and typically I would typically handle a post by either hooking into the wp_post action and access the $_POST request that way. Now I believe Craft is built on Yii which is an MVC framework but I cannot find any documentation showing how to handle post requests?

Any help or can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it through a plugin would be the easiest way.

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-guide.html

Your plugin would have a controller that the form would post to, then you'd grab the data from POST and do whatever you want with it.

A good example of this you can look at is the [Guest Entries](https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries) plugin, that allows "anonymous" front-end entry submissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking about this last night and I also came to the conclusion that a plugin may be the best way to handle this. I will give it a go!